# mysql_connect doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql

Heres my code. Simple.

```
<?php
echo 'start<br>';

//Do the conntection
$checkconnection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'rootpass');

//Check if it's valid
if(!$checkconnection) {

    echo 'CheckFailed';

} else{


    echo 'CheckSucess';

}

echo 'end'; ?>
```

but I only can see 'start'. There is no 'CheckFailed', 'CheckSucess', 'end'

What should I do?

I already install mysql, create database, create tables, of course.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: mysql_connect will be removed from future versions of php. Add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the beginning of the script to see more errors and use die( mysql_error());

Comment: Seems like `mysql_connect` hit a fatal error, thus not displaying your other part of the code. Enable your error reporting first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  return false;
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table;");
?>
```